# Store complex object in TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tempdata

I've been trying to pass data to an action after a redirect by using TempData like so:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    TempData["ErrorMessages"] = ModelState;
    return RedirectToAction("Product", "ProductDetails", new { code = model.ProductCode });
}
```

but unfortunately it's failing with the following message:

> '`System.InvalidOperationException` The 
>   `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.SessionStateTempDataProvider'` cannot serialize an
>   object of type `'ModelStateDictionary'` to session state.'

I've found an issue in [the MVC project in Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2276), but while it explains why I'm getting this error, I can't see what would be a viable alternative.

One option would be to serialize the object to a json string and then deserialize it back and reconstruct the `ModelState`. Is this the best approach? Are there any potential performance issues I need to take into account?

And finally, are there any alternatives for either serializing complex object or using some other pattern that doesn't involve using `TempData`?

Comment: you should not be doing this. If the modelstate is not valid the default behaviour is just to return the same view with the invalid model. So you should only do this return View(model); and not redirect to action

Comment: This is just one example, I'm looking for a way to store any complex object in TempData, not necessarily ModelState. Also, there might be scenarios where you cannot follow your advice, which I agree is the best practice

Comment: @hjgraca the use case for this type of situation is a view that has multiple partial views for adding and editing a list of data. For example, the model for the view is actually a list of the models, then there is an inline add form that has its own model (whose errors need sent back) and then each item is edited inline as well (each having their own errors). This is done easily with client-side frameworks like Angular, but not quite so easy with Razor.

Comment: FYI, you can't just serialize to JSON because the ModelError class does not have the appropriate constructors. In fact, that's the one problem child, the internal ModelError classes. Therefore, I think the solution is to serialize the KVP and then deserialize that and add them back. I'll post those filters when I'm finished with them.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I'm doing something along these lines to store a custom class (not ModelState) in TempData. I was just wondering if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can create the extension methods like this:

```
public static class TempDataExtensions
{
    public static void Put<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        tempData[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
    {
        object o;
        tempData.TryGetValue(key, out o);
        return o == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
    }
}
```

And, you can use them as follows:

Say `objectA` is of type `ClassA`. You can add this to the temp data dictionary using the above mentioned extension method like this:

`TempData.Put("key", objectA);`

And to retrieve it you can do this:

`var value = TempData.Get<ClassA>("key")`
where `value` retrieved will be of type `ClassA`

Comment: Works like a charm.  Love Newtonsoft!

Comment: I also fixed this by marking adding the `Serializable` attribute to the class that I was using for the object being placed into `TempData`

Comment: @brendonparker This didn't work for me, probably just depends on the object. The above code seems to be copypasted everywhere and IMO is bound to lead to a confusing controller and view setup.

Comment: @brendonparker i have used [Serializable()] attribute and implemented ISerializable, but it didn't work. can you share your solution?

Comment: I can confirm it worked with my Razor pages (net 5.0) project, with a `List<string>`. But then I tried calling `Put()` with a simple `string` and the whole TempData was wiped out for some weird reason. So for the `string` I had to use the `Add()` method.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida For string, int, or bool values, just use "TempData[key] = value;" directly.

Comment: What do I have to change to make this work with Type `decimal` and `long`?

Comment: @duichwer Maybe create separate extension methods to support those types?

Answer (score 21):

**Using [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) in .Net core 3.1 & above**

```
using System.Text.Json;

    public static class TempDataHelper
    {
        public static void Put<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value) where T : class
        {
            tempData[key] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
        {
            tempData.TryGetValue(key, out object o);
            return o == null ? null : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>((string)o);
        }

        public static T Peek<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
        {
            object o = tempData.Peek(key);
            return o == null ? null : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>((string)o);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you included    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="5.0.1" /> in *.csproj?

Comment: Damn, I didn't realize it was a package. I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 18):

I can not comment but I added a PEEK as well which is nice to check if there or read and not remove for the next GET.

```
public static T Peek<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
{
    object o = tempData.Peek(key);
    return o == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
}
```

Example

```
var value = TempData.Peek<ClassA>("key") where value retrieved will be of type ClassA
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having problems while saving a class object in Tempdata and then retrieve that data in another action method in controller you can do is
Save class object data in Tempdata

```
Student ClsStudent= new Student 

ClsStudent =getstudent(Student_id):
Tempdata["Studentdata"]= ClsStudent;
```

After that using that tempdata in other methods

```
Student clsStudent = null;
ClsStudent= (Student)Tempdata["Studentdata"]
```

Now you can use this class object data as before .Here we provide the Tempdata to class objects .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35739939)