# asp.net MVC6 Implementing a tagbuilder class and get error on ".ToString"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tagbuilder

I am getting compile errors when attempting to implement the message class from [Levelnis](http://levelnis.co.uk/blog/send-success-message-to-view-using-tempdata)'s Blog.

The class in question is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace Notifier.Helpers.MessageNotifier
{
    public class Message
    {
        public MessageSeverity Severity { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string Generate()
        {
            var isDismissable = Severity != MessageSeverity.Danger;
            if (Severity == MessageSeverity.None) Severity = MessageSeverity.Info;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
            divTag.AddCssClass("alert fade in");
            divTag.AddCssClass("alert-" + Severity.ToString().ToLower());


            var spanTag = new TagBuilder("span");
            spanTag.MergeAttribute("id", "MessageContent");

            if (isDismissable)
            {
                divTag.AddCssClass("alert-dismissable");
            }

            sb.Append(divTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

            if (isDismissable)
            {
                var buttonTag = new TagBuilder("button");
                buttonTag.MergeAttribute("class", "close");
                buttonTag.MergeAttribute("data-dismiss", "alert");
                buttonTag.MergeAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
                buttonTag.InnerHtml = "×";
                sb.Append(buttonTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
            }

            sb.Append(spanTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
            sb.Append(Text);
            sb.Append(spanTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
            sb.Append(divTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting two errors - the first relates to ".ToString" on the line:

```
sb.Append(divTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
```

and it says:

```
No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments
```

The second error relates to the line:

```
buttonTag.InnerHtml = "×";
```

and it says:

```
Property or indexer 'TagBuilder.InnerHtml' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

I have had a look at the documentation and other posts but so far I have not found anything that can help me modify this to compile correctly...

Are these methods implemented differently in Asp.net-core and if not can someone suggest another way of doing these lines?

Comment: I would suggest looking to [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/274/introducing-taghelpers-in-asp-net-mvc-6) tutorial. Instead of a tagbuilder you will be using a taghelper. I think it will resolve in cleaner and more understandable code & html

Comment: Thanks Tom. I decided to stepback and change my approach to creating Tempdata messages - see My answer..

Answer (score 4):

It seems TagBuilder does not work the same in MVC6 as it was in MVC5.

Instead of the `ToString()` method use `StringWriter` and the `WriteTo()` method as below:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");  
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
  tag.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
  result.Append(writer.ToString());
}
```

To set the `InnerHtml` use the `Append()` method as below:

```
tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());
```

This way it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was all to do with implementing a way of placing messages on the subsequent page - initially using Levilnis's Blog.

Not able to implement this without issues I stepped back and looked for another way of doing this. I used an approach presented by [Mister James](http://jameschambers.com/2014/06/day-14-bootstrap-alerts-and-mvc-framework-tempdata/) and in particular using a baseController to hold all my possible messages. I simplified it a bit as I didn't need to run multiple messages - just one per page.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public void Success(string message, bool dismissable = false)
    {
        AddAlert(AlertStyles.Success, message, dismissable);
    }

    public void Information(string message, bool dismissable = false)
    {
        AddAlert(AlertStyles.Information, message, dismissable);
    }

    public void Warning(string message, bool dismissable = false)
    {
        AddAlert(AlertStyles.Warning, message, dismissable);
    }

    public void Danger(string message, bool dismissable = false)
    {
        AddAlert(AlertStyles.Danger, message, dismissable);
    }

    private void AddAlert(string alertStyle, string message, bool dismissable)
    {
        var alert = new Alert
        {
            AlertStyle = alertStyle,
            Message = message,
            Dismissable = dismissable
        };

         TempData.Put(Alert.TempDataKey, alert);
    }

}
```

There was a wrinkle in that you cannot, in MVC6, send complex objects using Tempdata. This was solved using @Hem's answer in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638823/store-complex-object-in-tempdata-in-mvc-6) where he suggests using an extension that converts the complex object into a json string. For this to work I did have t oadd the using "using Newtonsoft.Json;".

```
public static class TempDataExtensions
{
    public static void Put<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        tempData[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
    {
        object o;
        tempData.TryGetValue(key, out o);
        return o == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
    }
}
```

This now works like a charm.