# Persist Querystring Parameter across page requests

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What's the best way in ASP.NET Core MVC to globally persist the querystring parameters? For instance, let's say I have "?t=1" in the URL. I would like that parameter to persist when clicking any link within the application. I would like to avoid controller or view specific code as this needs to be global. Can I use a Middleware for something like this?

Comment: Please don't use the MVC6 tags, it's now named "ASP.NET Core MVC"

Answer (score 0):

Query string values are read-only in terms of request/responses. You cannot set the query string for a response other than redirecting to a URL with the query string included.

Technically: there is no `Query` property on a `HttpContext.Response`, only in the `Request`.

You should either make sure to add the query string value to *every* URL on your website, or use another state mechanism such as TempData or session state to persist values across requests. This can easily be implemented using middleware.

Example: [Store complex object in TempData in MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638823/store-complex-object-in-tempdata-in-mvc-6).

Comment: The app is completely stateless, so storing state is not an option. I wonder if the best best is to somehow override the anchor tag helper.

Comment: @GrandMasterT if I'm not mistaken it's possible to configure the temp data provider to use a cookie for persisting data which keeps your application stateless. I'm not sure on the details though.