# Asp.net core TempData give 500 error when adding list and redirect to another view

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tempdata

I am try to build alerts list and added them to `TempData`. But it work if I did not do redirect. When I do redirect it give me 500 error. I set break point in view as well but it did not hit when did redirect other wise it hit correctly.

ActionMethod

```
public IActionResult Create(CategoryCreateVM input)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var category = mapper.Map<Categories>(input);
        categoryBL.Add(category);

        List<Alert> alert = new List<Alert>();
        alert.Add(new Alert("alert-success", "success message"));
        alert.Add(new Alert("alert-danger", "danger message"));

        TempData["Alert"] = alert;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(input);
}
```

How I access in view.

```
@{ 
    var alerts = TempData["Alert"] as List<Alert>;
}
@if (alerts != null && alerts.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="">
        @foreach (var alert in alerts)
        {
            <div class="alert @alert.AlertClass alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                @alert.Message
            </div>

        }
    </div>

}
```

Stack Trace.

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MvcSandbox.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MvcSandbox) in 46.4619ms
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request

System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'MvcSandbox.Controllers.Alert'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer.EnsureObjectCanBeSerialized(Object item) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\Internal\TempDataSerializer.cs:line 207
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer.Serialize(IDictionary`2 values) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\Internal\TempDataSerializer.cs:line 142
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.SessionStateTempDataProvider.SaveTempData(HttpContext context, IDictionary`2 values) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\ViewFeatures\SessionStateTempDataProvider.cs:line 62
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionary.Save() in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\ViewFeatures\TempDataDictionary.cs:line 166
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.SaveTempData(IActionResult result, ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory, HttpContext httpContext) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\Internal\SaveTempDataFilter.cs:line 91
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\Internal\SaveTempDataFilter.cs:line 80
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core\Internal\ControllerActionInvoker.cs:line 1023
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext() in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core\Internal\ControllerActionInvoker.cs:line 1105
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core\Internal\ControllerActionInvoker.cs:line 1377
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core\Internal\ControllerActionInvoker.cs:line 493
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext() in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core\Internal\ControllerActionInvoker.cs:line 164
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\temp\Session-dev\Session-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session\SessionMiddleware.cs:line 106
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\temp\Session-dev\Session-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session\SessionMiddleware.cs:line 123
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Error: Connection id "0HL1I8OFS17SU": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

System.InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_Session()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.SessionStateTempDataProvider.SaveTempData(HttpContext context, IDictionary`2 values) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\ViewFeatures\SessionStateTempDataProvider.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionary.Save() in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\ViewFeatures\TempDataDictionary.cs:line 166
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.SaveTempData(IActionResult result, ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory, HttpContext httpContext) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\Internal\SaveTempDataFilter.cs:line 91
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.<>c.<OnResultExecuting>b__5_0(Object state) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\Internal\SaveTempDataFilter.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.<FireOnStarting>d__178.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An exception was thrown attempting to display the error page.

System.ObjectDisposedException: The response has been aborted due to an unhandled application exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_Session()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.SessionStateTempDataProvider.SaveTempData(HttpContext context, IDictionary`2 values) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\ViewFeatures\SessionStateTempDataProvider.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionary.Save() in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\ViewFeatures\TempDataDictionary.cs:line 166
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.SaveTempData(IActionResult result, ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory, HttpContext httpContext) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\Internal\SaveTempDataFilter.cs:line 91
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.<>c.<OnResultExecuting>b__5_0(Object state) in D:\temp\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures\Internal\SaveTempDataFilter.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.<FireOnStarting>d__178.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.ThrowResponseAbortedException()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.<ProduceStartAndFireOnStartingAwaited>d__194.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.Write(ArraySegment`1 data)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.RazorViews.BaseView.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.RazorViews.ErrorPage.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.RazorViews.BaseView.<ExecuteAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Error: Connection id "0HL1I8OFS17SU": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

Comment: And what does the stack trace show?

Comment: Strack trace not shown, it gives localhost not working Error code 500

Comment: Enable logging to see the stack trace

Comment: None of these solutions below worked for me. I'd rather not deal with serialize to JSON but if I have to...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I figured it out what's the issue after digging into the source code. `Asp.Net Core MVC` not supported complex data type for `TempData` currently. It only support `string` for now. It through this exception while serialize data, if we pass other then `string`.

> The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'MvcSandbox.Controllers.Alert'.

I serialize my list to json and then save in `TempData`.

Here is how I did this. I create extension method to add and retrieve data from `TempData`.

```
const string Alerts = "Alerts";
public static List<Alert> GetAlert(this ITempDataDictionary tempData)
{
    CreateAlertTempData(tempData);
    return DeserializeAlerts(tempData[Alerts] as string);
}

public static void CreateAlertTempData(this ITempDataDictionary tempData)
{
    if (!tempData.ContainsKey(Alerts))
    {
        tempData[Alerts] = "";
    }
}
public static void AddAlert(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, Alert alert)
{
    if(alert == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(alert));
    }
    var deserializeAlertList = tempData.GetAlert();
    deserializeAlertList.Add(alert);
    tempData[Alerts] = SerializeAlerts(deserializeAlertList);
}
public static string SerializeAlerts(List<Alert> tempData)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempData);
}
public static List<Alert> DeserializeAlerts(string tempData)
{
    if(tempData.Length == 0)
    {
        return new List<Alert>();
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Alert>>(tempData);
}
```

Add Alert it `TempData`

```
 tempData.AddAlert(new Alert(AlertClass, Message));
```

Finally get 'TempData`in`View' and display.

```
@if (TempData.GetAlert().Count > 0)
{
    <div class="alert-container">
        @foreach (var alert in TempData.GetAlert())
        {
            <div class="alert @alert.AlertClass alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                @alert.Message
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Had the same problem but liked this solution better.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638823/store-complex-object-in-tempdata

Comment: @StephenMcDowell Thanks a lot, your solution helped me too in my ASP.NET Core 2 project. much appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Did you configure Session? TempData is using session behind the scenes.

Project.json

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0"
```

Here is the Startup.cs file. - `ConfigureServices` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

And `Configure` method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Now try with TempData, it will work.

And you can set the environment with `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` environment variable.

Comment: Still, you have the problem? What is the stack trace? If you are running from command line, what is the exception you're getting?

Comment: @Sami-Kuhmonen  Stack trace added.

Comment: @Ahmar Is the stack trace before enabling the session? I could see an exception related to session - `System.InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_Session()`

Comment: I this is strange although I setup session correctly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state
Helped me properly setup session state to get rid of my error.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me either :( but I'll check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to enable Session and Temp data on Core Runtime 2.0.6.

ConfigureServices Section of Startup

```
// Add MVC service.
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    // Configure global usage of antiforgery tokens.
    config.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
})
.AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

// Adds the ability to use session variables.
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});
```

Comment: Well this was a long time ago and everything has changed in Core 2.0.6 Runtime. It is close though. I updated comment with what I use now to enable Session and Temp data. Site also required SSL to work properly these days even if it is a local temp cert for development within VS. TBH, don't remember this question and this is a bit off-topic moreless just filling setup information for those in need.