# RedirectToAction is Passing a Null Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm pasting a code snippet below of a c# control. What I can't figure out is that the formViewModel that I'm taking into AddPerson is properly populated, but then when I call to RedirectToAction to the "SaveForm" method right below and I pass the formViewModel, it comes in empty to the "SaveForm" method.

Any advice on what I'm not understanding?

Thanks,

```
            [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddPerson(GikFormViewModel formViewModel)
        {
            if(formViewModel.Items == null)
            {
                //formViewModel.Items.Add(new GikItemViewModel() { })
                formViewModel.Items = new List<GikItemViewModel>();
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index", formViewModel);
            }

        // REDIRECTING HERE TO "SaveForm" Formatting is not properly done

            return RedirectToAction("SaveForm", formViewModel);
            //return View("Index", formViewModel);
        }

        public IActionResult SaveForm(GikFormViewModel formViewModel)
        {
            var person = formViewModel.Person;
            var items = formViewModel.Items;
            var gikItems = new Collection<Gikitem>();
            //var gikPerson = new Gikperson();
            //var gikItem = new Gikitem();
            var gikPerson = new Gikperson()
            {
                Organization = person.Organization,
                Title = person.Title,
                Name = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,

                AddressLineOne = person.AddressLineOne,
                AddressLineTwo = person.AddressLineTwo == null ? null : person.AddressLineTwo,
                City = person.City,
                State = person.State,
                Zipcode = person.Zipcode,
                Phone = person.Phone,
                DoNoContact = person.DoNotContact == true ? 1 : 2,
                Email = person.Email
            };
```

Comment: You cannot pass a model which contains complex properties or collections using `RedirectToAction` (look at the url you are generating to undersand - the method does not perform recursion to generate query string values for complex properties)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [TempData](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc).

> TempData in ASP.NET MVC can be used to store temporary data which can be used in the subsequent request. TempData will be cleared out after the completion of a subsequent request.

**AddPerson action**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPerson(GikFormViewModel formViewModel)
{
    if(formViewModel.Items == null)
    {
        //formViewModel.Items.Add(new GikItemViewModel() { })
        formViewModel.Items = new List<GikItemViewModel>();
    }
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Index", formViewModel);
    }

    //Save the model into the TempData object.
    TempData["model] = formViewModel;

    return RedirectToAction("SaveForm");
    //return View("Index", formViewModel);
}
```

**SaveForm action**

```
public IActionResult SaveForm()
{
    //If TempData doesn't contains your model then return error message or something.
    if(!TempData.ContainsKey("model"))
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();

    //Retrieve the model from TempData object.
    var formViewModel = TempData["model"] as GikFormViewModel;

    var person = formViewModel.Person;
    var items = formViewModel.Items;
    var gikItems = new Collection<Gikitem>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks. That's so weird that I've been doing this a year and haven't come across this issue yet. I tried this out and the model is saving to the TempData so it does work but there's an issue. What's weird is that I then get a 500 server error on the `RedirectToAction("SaveForm")`. I'm not passing the formViewModel nor am I taking it as a parameter anymore. Code looks just like yours. But if I comment out the `TempData["model"] = formViewModel;` then I no longer get the 500 error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413395/asp-net-core-tempdata-give-500-error-when-adding-list-and-redirect-to-another-vi

Comment: The link above could be helpful. I will try those steps. But they are saying to set environment "development" variable so what about production? Otherwise maybe it's possible that I create and save to a model before sending to save form.

Comment: I am using .Net Core which may have been a good thing to share as well.

Comment: While I'm not completely sure why it is erroring when you add a complex object to TempData and then RedirectToAction..I do know if you serialize the object first and then deserialize it works fine:  

TempData["model"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formViewModel);

var formView = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormViewModel>(TempData["model"].ToString());

Comment: I'm also trying `HttpContext.Items` as well. What's weird is both TempData and the HttpContext saves the model correctly. Before redirecting I can view both of these and the keys are properly set and the objects are properly set as values with exact structure and everything. But then I either get 500 with the TempData or with HttpContext, it turns up to be empty when I check from the next method. I am totally blown away right now. I've never seen where I couldn't send a model before. Even if I create and populate an entirely new one. I'm just blown away.