# TempData.Keep() in asp.net core returning localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When using TempData.Keep() in asp.net core I'm getting "localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500". When I remove TempData.Keep() no issues but I'm not getting data in the next action method. I followed this link "[TempData null in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734039/tempdata-null-in-asp-net-core)" however it is not fixing my problem

```
 Controller code:
 model.masterDataViewModel = masterDataPaginated;
 TempData["adhocMasterData"] = model.masterDataViewModel;
 return View();

View code:
ViewData["Title"] = "BeaconAdhocJob - Dashboard view";
var adhocMaserData = (IEnumerable<DashBoardViewModel.AdhocMasterViewModel>)TempData["adhocMasterData"];
TempData.Keep();
```

Comment: Post the actual exception and stack trace. The error is just a generic 500 and tells us nothing. If you're running in Visual Studio, you'll be able to see this in the output pane, once you select `ASP.NET Core Web Server` from the output list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net core TempData give 500 error when adding list and redirect to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413395/asp-net-core-tempdata-give-500-error-when-adding-list-and-redirect-to-another-vi)

Comment: You should also check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638823/store-complex-object-in-tempdata