# How to pass ExpandoObject to another Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC, and trying to create a simple website. So, now I'm trying to reach my navigation bar items from another controller.

This is my `MenuController`:

```cs
private static List<Menu> GetMenus()
{
        List<Menu> menu = new()
        {
            new Menu { MenuId = 1, MenuName = "Elektronik" },
            new Menu { MenuId = 2, MenuName = "Moda" },
            new Menu { MenuId = 3, MenuName = "Ev Tekstil" },
            new Menu { MenuId = 4, MenuName = "Outdooe" }
        };
        return menu;
}

public List<AltMenu> GetAltMenus()
{
    List<AltMenu> altMenus = new()
        {
            new AltMenu { AltMenuId = 1, AltMenuName = "Televizyon", AnaMenuId = 1 },
            new AltMenu { AltMenuId = 2, AltMenuName = "Giyim", AnaMenuId = 2 },
            new AltMenu { AltMenuId = 3, AltMenuName = "Alt Menu", AnaMenuId = 2 },
            new AltMenu { AltMenuId = 4, AltMenuName = "Alt Menu", AnaMenuId = 3 },
            new AltMenu { AltMenuId = 5, AltMenuName = "Alt Menu", AnaMenuId = 3 },
            new AltMenu { AltMenuId = 6, AltMenuName = "Alt Menu", AnaMenuId = 4 }
        };

    return altMenus;
}
    
public ExpandoObject GetAllMenu()
{
    dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
    mymodel.Menu = GetMenus();
    mymodel.AltMenu = GetAltMenus();

    TempData["Menu"] = mymodel;

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", TempData["Menu"]);
}
```

Trying to reach this from `HomeController` (or another). So I can use my menu navbar in different pages without database.

PS.: I'm getting an error at the "return" line:

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult' to 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 errors here, first one is how you are using the temp data:

you don't need to add it as a parameter, your redirect should look like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

to use it on the Home controller all you need to do is this:

```
if(TempData.ContainsKey("Menu"))
   string mymodel = TempData["Menu"];
```

Second is, you don't store objects on tempdata, if you want to do that you should consider some type of serialization, [take a look a this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638823/store-complex-object-in-tempdata)

this extension method was taken from the previously provided link:

```
public static class TempDataExtensions
{
    public static void Put<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        tempData[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
    {
        object o;
        tempData.TryGetValue(key, out o);
        return o == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still gettin same error "CS0029".

Comment: @kmr i just updated my answer

Comment: Put<T> and Get<T> showing an error (CS1109). .Net Core 6 might be the problem here? Been searching for a few days. Really! Tried everything I see. Lots of codes I tried doesn't work on .Net Core 6.

Comment: Sorry for the flood... I tried a simple string redirect too. It return null as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `RedirectToAction()` method returns the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult` object inherited from  the `ActionResult`. Therefore you need to change your  the `public ExpandoObject GetAllMenu()` method declaration to `public IActionResult GetAllMenu()`.

See [ControllerBase.RedirectToAction Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Thanks for that. Fixed it but, still cannot pass "mymodel".

Comment: @kmr: It's because you don't need to save your model in the `TempData.` like you do:  `TempData["Menu"] = mymodel;`. **This is wrong approach.**  Just use `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", mymodel);`. If this will not work then problem in your `Index()` action method - add code of the `Index()` method to the question, please. the sentence _still cannot pass "mymodel"_ does not have useful information to understand your problem.

Comment: @kmr: Then in the `index.cshtml` you can define the data model as `dymanic` .