# Pass data between actions in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a coding beginner and I try to use MVC to built an employees management system,
here are my simplified code:

model

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set;}
    }
```

I have a textbox in Index View so that I could input some words to filter employee list.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index( string? searchString )
    {

         var employees = from e in _context.Employee select e;

         if (!searchString.IsNullOrEmpty())
         {
            employees = employees.Where(w => w.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
         }

         return View(employees)
    }
```

Now I wish to export the list to Excel, so I wrote an  `IActionResult ExportToExcel()`to do the job and put an button in Index View to trigger it.

But I don't know how to pass the data `employees` to action `ExoirtToExcel()` , I tested to export Excel without data and the action works fine.

I tried use TempData to storage data employees

```
  ...
  
  if (!searchString.IsNullOrEmpty())
  {
     employees = employees.Where(w => w.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
  }
  
  TempData["Employees"] = employees;

  return View(employees)
```

but got an exception
*'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Infrastructure.DefaultTempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type*

Is there anyway I can pass the data `employees` from Index action to another ?
Every advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to store a complex object list in your TempData. Please see the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638823/store-complex-object-in-tempdata

Comment: @Lukeric which type of data you want to expect json or whole empyee you pass?

Comment: @Lukeric use this one ```List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();``` then after use the list object in foreachloop  and add that list object in excel file

Comment: @ Rahul Patil  my data storages in sql data-base, I wish I could export the object "employees" which have been queried in Index action, not to query again in export action. @ SoftwareDveloper thank you , I will check the link.